# Is there any way to connect Acquia Cloud intance with issue tracker?

Tags: version-control, acquia-cloud

As in question, I'm looking for a way to connect any issue tracker with a development site hosted by Acquia Cloud.

I want to have a connection between git commits and issues.

Is this possible in Acquia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the combo of BitBucket/JIRA. There are many people that like GitHub's issue tracker too. Acquia has [tutorial](https://docs.acquia.com/cloud/manage/code/github) on setting up either service as a 2nd remote repo. Either service will give you a way to track issues against your commits.